# Remove Borders of XWPFTableRow

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a `XWPFTable` with borders and I add a page break inside:

```
addBreak(BreakType.PAGE)
```

In the next page I want to remove the border of the last `XWPFTableRow`, but I can't because this row doesn't provide access to the border. The border belongs to the table.

How I could remove the border of the last row?

Comment: Can you create a document with Word that is doing this? With this you could take a look how it is stored in the .docx (which is actually a zip containing XML files), POI usually allows to access some low-level APIs which then allow to do things like this if you know how things need to be set.

Comment: Thanks. One question more. How I can do with apachepoi this xml:
   `<w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="nil"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="nil"/>
    </w:tcBorders>code`

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how you can access/add the CTTcBorders object to set the flags as needed.

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    CTTbl ctTable = CTTbl.Factory.newInstance();
    XWPFTable table = new XWPFTable(ctTable, doc);
    XWPFTableRow tr = table.getRow(0);
    XWPFTableCell cell = tr.getCell(0);

    CTTc ctTc = cell.getCTTc();
    CTTcPr tcPr = ctTc.addNewTcPr();
    CTHMerge hMerge = tcPr.addNewHMerge();
    hMerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);

    CTTcBorders tblBorders = tcPr.addNewTcBorders();
```

For an existing document you will need to iterate through the objects to find the ones that you would like to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcBorders().addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.NIL);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remove middle borders just for some rows and had to do more than just remove the right border.

I had to iterate for the desired cells and then, for the *i-th* cell (cell = row.get(i) ), remove the right border of the *i-th* cell **AND** the left border of the next cell (nextCell = row.get(i+1)).

The right border of one cell coincides with the left border of the next cell in the row, and i needed to hide both.

```
public void hideTableInnerBorders(XWPFTable table){
    // for the 5th and 6th rows (index 4,5),
    // hide the right border for the three middle columns (index 1,2,3)
    // and the left border on the three last columns (index 2,3,4)
    List<XWPFTableRow> rows = table.getRows();
    for( int rowIndex = 4; rowIndex < rows.size(); rowIndex++){ //  rowIndex:{4,5} - last two lines
        List<XWPFTableCell> cells = rows.get(rowIndex).getTableCells();
        for(int cellIndex = 1; cellIndex < cells.size(); cellIndex++){ //  cellIndex:{1,2,3,4}
            XWPFTableCell cell = cells.get(cellIndex);
            CTTcBorders tblBorders = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewTcBorders();

            // remove the right border for the indexes 1 2 3
            if( cellIndex == 1 || cellIndex == 2 || cellIndex == 3 ){
                tblBorders.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.NIL);
            }
            // remove the left border for the indexes 2,3,4
            if ( cellIndex == 2 || cellIndex == 3 || cellIndex == 4 ) {
                tblBorders.addNewLeft().setVal(STBorder.NIL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the outpus was:
[image]